# Grails Apps deployed in GlassFish doesn't works after reload

Tags: grails, groovy, glassfish, war

Everything works fine, building a WAR file and deploying it into glassfish. After reloading any applications, only the reloaded application works and other applications will fail.

Grails Runtime Exception
Error Details

Error 500: 
Servlet: default
URI: /CTS/user/login
Exception Message: No such property: params for class: web.UserController 
Caused by: No such property: params for class: web.UserController 
Class: Unknown 
At Line: [-1] 
Code Snippet:

Stack Trace

org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MissingPropertyExceptionNoStack: No such property: params for class: web.UserController

Comment: I've almost tried everything possible, configuring the datasource, configuring the glassfish. This problem still exists! Am I the only one with this issue?

Comment: I am having the same problem working with Tomcat. Only solution, to restart the tomcat container